# jsHint for NetBeans 8.0

Tags: netbeans, jslint, jshint, netbeans-8, netbeans-plugins

Is there any working hinter like that for 8.0.2.

Previously the jsHint worked fine (7.4 or so) - the one with config page under misc.
Its broken now and likely will never be fixed.
jsLint works - but it lacks proper config options so many of the annoying unneeded features stay on.

One of the primary  annoyances is the constant warnings everywhere when you use function() and wont add a space (company inhouse formatting rule).

Comment: I would also like to switch off "using function before defined", that influences my coding style order in closures.

Answer (score 1):

Install all three available at Netbeans Plugin Portal at once:

- [pangaiz](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/58580/jshint)
- [luka-zitnik](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/57838/jshint-for-netbeans)
- [benesch](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/52226/jshint)